# Creating colored roles in discord through discord.py gives error

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I want to make coloured roles with the help of a command, so that whenever I do `.cr` the bot creates the roles specified in the code. For example, my code is:

```
    async def cr(self, ctx):
        guild = self.client.get_guild(783547639944839178)
        channel = self.client.get_channel(809683610058752010)
        await guild.create_role(name="red", colour=discord.Colour(2452332))
        await guild.create_role(name="skyblue", colour=discord.Colour(17167187))
        await guild.create_role(name="yellow", colour=discord.Colour(24821016))
        await channel.send("Done.")
```

Firstly, when I do this command, it does create a role named red; but its colour is "#256b6c" instead of "#F51720". I used an online hex to RGB converted to convert these values.

Second, it doesn't execute the next line and gives this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In color: int value should be less than or equal to 16777215.
```

I used the same converter again. Where am I going wrong?
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error pretty much speaks for itself, the values that you're passing are invalid, if you try converting the integers you get the next hex values

```py
>>> hex(2452332)
0x2566b6c
>>> hex(17167187)
0x105f353
>>> hex(24821016)
0x17abd18
```

As you can see instead of being 6 digits long they're of length 7 (not including the `0x`). I'm not entirely sure what colors you're trying to get but they're invalid. If you want to create a role knowing it's hex value:

```py
color = int("ff0000", 16)
# Or
color = 0xff0000

await guild.create_role(..., colour=color)
```

Both solutions will work

Answer (score 0):

Integers are stored on 8bits in the memory, and the number you try to pass doesn't fit on those 8bits. At least that's what the error says. To fix your problem, if you have access to the variable, cast it to something else or try to find another way to pass the color... I'd go for the second solution, specially if you don't get the right color ;)